# Lazarus (Pascal) How to connect to SQL Server using ODBC or TMSSQLConnection?

Tags: sql-server, pascal, lazarus

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and my PC is 32 bit. I created an **ODBC Data Source** in the "Administrative Tools". I used the server name `(My PC name)\SQL2008R2` which is the instance name and I used Windows Authentication instead of using username and password.

[image]

In Lazarus, I used the ODBC Connection and when I try to set the property "Connected" to true I get this error:

[image]

And I tried to use also the SQL Server connection with the "dblib.dll" and got an error.

Note: I tried to paste the dll file in `C:\Windows\System32` folder and in the `C:\lazarus` but still getting same error.

[image]

Comment: make sure you have a matching dblib.dll (depending on 32-bit/64-bit windows). You can get the alternate versions here: ftp://ftp.freepascal.org/fpc/contrib/windows/

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with Pascal/Lazarus, but the ODBC error message in the first screenshot suggests that the property names in the Lazarus configuration screen don't match the property names used by ODBC; the error says:

> Could not connect with connection string "DSN=jbs..."

Based on the screenshot of your ODBC system DSN, the DSN name is `DBSource`. Try setting value of the `DatabaseName` to `DBSource` in the Lazarus ODBC connection configuration screen.